# Uploading docx file in Zend Framework with mime type fails?

Tags: php, file, zend-framework, upload, docx

i am trying to upload resume to my website from users

so i have resticted the file upload too doc,pdf,and docx

ms word doc files are uploading fine along with pdf but docx files are coming in with

application/zip mime type so file does not get uploaded

how to do correct mime type checking so that docx file uploads as other files

below is my code

```
$config = Zend_Registry::get ( 'config' );

            $files_path = $config->resume->path;

            $adapter = new Zend_File_Transfer ();

            // Limit the MIME type of all given files to gif and jpeg images
            $adapter->addValidator ( 'MimeType', false, array ('application/msword','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document','application/pdf' ) ); 


        $files = $adapter->getFileInfo ();


        $file_name = null;
        $tmpArr = null;

        foreach ( $files as $file => $info ) {
            if (! empty ( $info ['name'] )) {
                $tmpArr = explode ( ".", $info ['name'] );
            }
        }

        if (! empty ( $tmpArr )) {
            //$file_name = $tmpArr [0] . "-" . $post ['id'] . "." . $tmpArr [1];
            $file_name = $tmpArr [0] . "-" . $post ['id'] . "." . $tmpArr [count ( $tmpArr ) - 1];
            $adapter->setDestination ( $files_path );

            $adapter->addFilter ( 'Rename', array ('target' => $files_path . DS . $file_name, 'overwrite' => true ) );
            if ($adapter->receive ()) {
                // # =  # = # = # = # = # = # = # = # = # = # = # = # = # = # = # = # =
                $arrayKeys = array_keys ( $files );
                $actual_file_name = $tmpArr [0] . "." . $tmpArr [1];
                $uploaded_file_name = $adapter->getFileName ( $arrayKeys [0], false );
                if ($actual_file_name == $uploaded_file_name) {
                    rename ( $files_path . DS . $actual_file_name, $files_path . DS . $file_name );
                }
                // # =  # = # = # = # = # = # = # = # = # = # = # = # = # = # = # = # =


                $post ['filename'] = $file_name;
                $result = $employeeModel->updateEmployeeResume ( $post );
                $old_file = $files_path . DS . $post ['c_image_name'];
                if (file_exists ( $old_file )) {
                    @unlink ( $old_file );
                }

                $this->_flashMessenger->addMessage ( 'Resume added successfully' );
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

DOCX is basically a ZIP file (you can extract them with your favourite unzipper, try it!), so you must allow ZIP files if you want your users to be able to upload DOCX files.

Comment: ya that i know sometime get it has application/zip or application/octet-stream

Answer (score 0):

i have added a temporaray fix in zend

// allowing zip files to upload

```
     $adapter->addValidator ( 'MimeType', false, array ('application/msword','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document','application/pdf','application/zip' ) );
```

// disallowing files with .zip  to upload and getting docx files uploaded hence .

```
    $adapter->addValidator('Extension', false, 'doc,docx,pdf');
```